# How to cut one bitmap from other bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to cut Bitmap1 from Bitmap2..
For example, i have Bitmap1 (decode from Resources drawable) and Bitmap2 (decode from Resources drawable too).

Bitmap1:

```
|   |
 > <
|   |
```

Bitmap2:

```
|xxx|
|xxx|
|xxx|
```

I need result:

```
|xxx|
 >x<
|xxx|
```

Can somebody give me sample code?

Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load both bitmaps and use `PorterDuffXfermode` and `DST_IN` to mask "Bitmap2", sort of like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap2);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap1);
Bitmap bitmap2MaskedByBitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight(), bitmap2.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap2MaskedByBitmap1);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(false);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);
bitmap2.recycle();
bitmap1.recycle();

// bitmap2MaskedByBitmap1 should now contain the desired image
// as long as your Bitmap1 mask isn't sh-t.
```

Comment: !! Great! Thank! But now I have image with black background... Can I do it with empty (alpha 0) background?